# Pass hosts from master playbook to included playbook

Tags: linux, ansible

How can I pass the *hosts* from a master playbook to an included playbook?

I'm trying to create a master playbook for a type of server (e.g., a web server) which shares some common playbooks with other types of servers (e.g., gateway server, database server, etc.). I'm running Ansible 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

The *inventory* file is:

```ini
[web-servers]
192.168.0.217

[db-servers]
192.168.0.218
```

The master playbook *deploy-web-servers.yml* is:

```yaml
---
- hosts: web-servers
  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostvars

- include: setup-common.yml
  vars:
    server: "{{ hostvars['inventory_hostname'] }}"
```

The included playbook *setup-common.yml* is:

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ server }}" 
  tasks:
    - debug: var=server
```

When I run this using the command:

```shell
ansible-playbook deploy-web-servers.yml -i inventory
```

It outputs:

```
PLAY [web-servers] ************************************************************ 

TASK: [debug var=hostvars] **************************************************** 
ok: [192.168.0.217] => {
    "var": {
        "hostvars": {
            "group_names": [
                "web-servers"
            ],
            "groups": {
                "all": [
                    "192.168.0.218",
                    "192.168.0.217"
                ],
                "db-servers": [
                    "192.168.0.218"
                ],
                "ungrouped": [],
                "web-servers": [
                    "192.168.0.217"
                ]
            },
            "inventory_hostname": "192.168.0.217",
            "inventory_hostname_short": "192"
        }
    }
}

PLAY [{{ hostvars['inventory_hostname'] }}] *********************************** 
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
192.168.0.217              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The included playbook *setup-common.yml* is never run because the host was not successfully forwarded as indicated by the lines:

```
PLAY [{{ hostvars['inventory_hostname'] }}] *********************************** 
skipping: no hosts matched
```

How can I forward the host to the included playbook?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

```
- include: setup-common.yml
  vars:
    server: "{{ hostvars['inventory_hostname'] }}"
```

You do not need to specify this variable at all, nor should you be attempting to use it in the other playbook. By default the playbook will run for all hosts that *it* specifies. So don't do this, and just write a normal playbook.

Comment: All of the hosts are applicable to *setup-common.yml* (and others), but I want to constrain the hosts depending on what master playbook includes it. I'm trying to run multiple, stand alone playbooks in sequence but only for the specific hosts specified by the master playbook. I would really prefer not split up the playbooks into a hundred different roles and `main.yml` files so I thought including playbooks would be a straight forward way accomplish what I want.